# Check if specific checkbox on html table with multiple checkboxes is checked. JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this table which I populate from database and I want to check foreach row whether if the checkbox on `Enviar` column is checked using **JS/JQuery**.

```js
function Enviar() {
  var TableData = new Array();

  $('#dtBasicExample tr').each(function(row, tr) {

      if ($(tr).find('td:eq(10)').checked == true) //check if checkbox is checked
      {
        alert('check');
      }
    })
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tipo Documento<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
      <th>Nº Electrónico<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
      <th style="width: 200px;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkTotal" />Aceptación</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" id="checktodas" />Enviar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Factura</td>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' id='chbTotal' name='Total' value='Total'>Total<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Parcial' value='Parcial'>Parcial<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Rechazo' value='Rechazo'>Rechazo
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chcktbl' /> Enviar
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Factura</td>
      <td>002</td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' id='chbTotal' name='Total' value='Total'>Total<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Parcial' value='Parcial'>Parcial<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Rechazo' value='Rechazo'>Rechazo
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chcktbl' /> Enviar
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generaly you can check the state of the checkbox in jQuery using: `.prop(checked)`. It will return a boolean value wehter the the checkbox is checked or not.

See: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Also be shure to check the right element. You need to get the right checkbox. In your case i queried for the one with class `chcktbl` wich was always the "Enviar" one.

```js
function Enviar() {
  var TableData = new Array();
  $('#dtBasicExample tr').each(function(row, tr) {
    if ($(tr).find('td .chcktbl').prop('checked') == true) //check if checkbox is checked
    {
      $(tr).find('td .chcktbl').parent().addClass('active');
    }else {
      $(tr).find('td .chcktbl').parent().removeClass('active');
    }
  })
}
  
document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', function () {
  Enviar();
})
```

```css
.active{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tipo Documento<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
      <th>Nº Electrónico<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
      <th style="width: 200px;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkTotal" />Aceptación</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" id="checktodas" />Enviar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Factura</td>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' id='chbTotal' name='Total' value='Total'>Total<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Parcial' value='Parcial'>Parcial<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Rechazo' value='Rechazo'>Rechazo
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chcktbl' /> Enviar
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Factura</td>
      <td>002</td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' id='chbTotal' name='Total' value='Total'>Total<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Parcial' value='Parcial'>Parcial<br>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chb' name='Rechazo' value='Rechazo'>Rechazo
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='chcktbl' /> Enviar
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<button id="check">check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

At plain view, I see that there is a syntax mistake.

From this:

```
function Enviar()
{
    var TableData = new Array();

    $('#dtBasicExample tr').each(function(row, tr)
    {

        if($(tr).find('td:eq(10)').checked==true)//check if checkbox is checked
        {
           alert('check');  
        }
    }
}
```

There is a missing `);` that belongs to `each()`:

```
function Enviar()
{
    var TableData = new Array();

    $('#dtBasicExample tr').each(function(row, tr)
    {

        if($(tr).find('td:eq(10)').checked==true)//check if checkbox is checked
        {
           alert('check');  
        }
    }); // << THE ); WAS MISSING HERE. THIS WAS PRODUCING AN ERROR
}
```

Please let me know if that solves your issue.